# JSON Parse = > SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: node.js, json, api, express

I try to get information from server but got on error if want to parse the answer.

My code:

```
const data = ["10093"]

const options = {
    auth: userpsw,
    method: 'GET',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS: data
};

const request = http.request(url, options, function(response) {
  response.on("data", function(data){
    console.log(JSON.parse(data));
  })
})
```

Answer:

```
undefined:1
<br />
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

If I do not parse the data:

```
const request = http.request(url, options, function(response) {
  response.on("data", function(data){
    console.log(data);
```

Then I get a following massage:

```
Buffer 3c 62 72 20 2f 3e 0a 3c 62 3e 57 61 72 6e 69 6e 67 3c 2f 62 3e 3a 20 20 69 6d 70 6c 6f 64 65 28 29 3a 20 49 6e 76 61 6c 69 64 20 61 72 67 75 6d 65 6e ... 282 more bytes
```

What I can not see? How to read the answer?

Comment: Your resource is not returning JSON. It's returning text starting with `<br />\n<b>Warning</b>:  implode(): Invalid argumen` (that's what the buffer text you've shown says).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use request module instead of HTTP :

```
var options = {
    hostname: '_your_url',
    port: 'your_port',
    path: '/your_path',
    method: 'GET',
    json:true
}
request(options, function(error, response, body){
    if(error) console.log(error);
    else console.log(body);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response is not a JSON format that's why you got error when you try to parse the response use try and catch for handle errors.